# Как из .txt файла выносить рандомную строчку и выписывать для юзера в чате вк на python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

У меня есть код, как при вводе фразы Бот, скажи слово, из .txt файла бралась 1 рандомная строчка и выводилась юзеру. Желательно чтоб эта строчка не повторялась
Библиотека vkapi

```
import vk_api, random
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = '800df4012535b065a9759a6b0abf1677aee086137a4ca8600bc7e019234a046959b56e9353ba753151cf2')
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpool = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})



for event in longpool.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:

            msg = event.text.lower() 
            id = event.user_id

            if msg == 'дарова кабан':
                send(id, 'дарова')

            else: 
                send(id, 'я понимаю только "дарова кабан"')
```

Comment: Строчка в каком смысле? Линия? Слово? Или буквально набор символов (скажем, по половинке слов)?

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: В строчке цифра + слово пример: 1 слово.   Не получается понять именно как это сделать

Comment: Создайте файл с текстом на каждой строке. Прочитайте его и `random.choice` возьмите случайную строку.

Comment: Вы не читали предупреждений в духе «этот токен вроде вашего пароля от аккаунта»?

Answer (score 0):

Приведите файл к удобному для парсинга вида: .. + цифра + слово + разделитель + .. . Может к "28 октября;1999 полнолуния". Получите наборы выражений (цифра + слово) используя `str.split(';')`. Получится список наборов, нужных вам для вывода. Используйте random.choice чтобы выбрать случайный набор. Чтобы убрать повторы, можно сделать

```
index=random.randint(0, len(наборы))
set=наборы.pop(index)
```

Таким образом, случайные наборы не будут повторятся. Но потребуется проверка на перезагрузку наборов так как они могут закончиться.